# Quebra de texto

Tags: java, array

Estou tentando fazer uma quebra de linha em um `Array`, porém não estou tendo sucesso ao tentar executar o `split()`, resumindo, eu quero fazer uma tabela de 10 linhas com 2 colunas que adquiram os valores de `list` e `list2`

```
public class Ultimos10 {

    public Ultimos10(ObjectOutputStream saida, Socket cliente) throws IOException {
        String resultados = NovoJogo.list.toString(); //Puxa Array da outra classe
        String resultados2 = NovoJogo.list2.toString();

        String quebra[]=resultados.split("\\n"); //Tentando colocar split
        String quebra2[]=resultados2.split("\\n");

        for(String resul:quebra){ //Imprime na tela do cliente
            saida.writeObject(resul+"\r\n");
        }

        for(String resul2:quebra){
            saida.writeObject(resul2);
        }

        Servidor serv = new Servidor();
        serv.Menu(cliente);
    }
}
```

Também tenho duvidas em relação a exclusão de uma linha e sortear
por resultados colocados por primeiro.

Comment: Qual o conteúdo de `resultados` e `resultados2`? Tens certeza que dar um `toString` em um array vai fazer o que você quer? E também, sua pergunta não está muito clara, tente [edita-la](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/87976/edit) e adicionar mais detalhes.

Comment: `resultados` e `resultados2` recebem o valores de duas `ArrayLists`, a `list` e `list2`, esse `Array` que quero criar precisa ser `String` para ser lida pelo cliente, pois foi dessa maneira que criei a parte de leitura do cliente, mas isso não vem ao caso, tava tentando fazer algo do tipo `String[][] res = new String[10][2];
  res[0][0] = resultados;
  res[0][1] = resultados2;`

mas da o erro `[[Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Comment: Ok, vamos por partes. Faça um `System.out.println(resultados);` e `System.out.println(resultados2);` e veja no console qual o **conteúdo** dessas duas variáveis.

Comment: O resultado esta correto, esta puxando as variaveis da `list` e `list2` corretamente

Comment: Mas eu preciso ver o **conteúdo** delas pra poder te ajudar. Outra coisa, no comentário acima você diz que está recebendo um erro, na sua pergunta não fala nada sobre erro. Coloque o erro na pergunta para que outras pessoas possam ver com clareza e te ajudar.

Comment: Ok, vou explicar o proposito do meu programa para que fique mais claro, eu tenho um cliente que recebe as informações e o servidor, esse servidor lança um numero randomico e o cliente "chuta" valores até acertar, no final eu preciso mostrar uma tabela que informa o número randomico que o server lançou e o numero de tentativas, ai vem o `resultado`(tentativas) e `resultado2`(numero randomico) o conteúdo sai assim `[tentativas, numRan, tentativas, numRan...]` eu preciso que fique `[ten, numRan]` ai na linha de baixo a mesma coisa `[ten, numRan]` no caso 10 linhas por 2 colunas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tenho mais o código, mas lembro que fiz da seguinte maneira:

`String variavel = System.getProperty("line.separator");`

ai quando queria quebrar a linha a linha eu puxava a variavel

Answer (score 1):

Se ambos os arrays tem o mesmo tamanho (tentativas) (randomico), então você pode simplificar seu método:

String tentativas[] = ...//Seu array de tentativas
    String numeroRamdomico[] = ...//Seu array de numero randomico

```
for (int i = 0; i < tentativas.length; i++) {
   System.out.println("Tentativa: " + tentativas[i] 
                    + " | Numero Randomico: " + numeroRamdomico[i]);
}
```

Dessa forma você está gerando sua lista com duas colunas e se quiser limitar a quantidade de linhas é só colocar ao invés de `tentativas.length` o valor que você quiser.

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela resposta, mas ja consegui aqui ;)

Comment: @MatheusLopes Se conseguiu de outra forma, poderia postar a solução como uma resposta?

Comment: @utluiz respondido, espero ter ajudado ;)